# Firebase: Accessing ArrayList Inside User Obeject

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to access the values that are stored in an arraylist under a user item called contacts. My Current code is located below but it throws an exception of failing to convert a hash map to string on the indicated line. If anyone has any tips on how to solve this or a better solution I would appreciate it.

```
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new 
     GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
            -> List<String> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
            Log.d("demo", yourStringArray.toString());
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the attributes under `contacts`:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userid).child("contacts");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String dept=datas.child("dept").getValue().toString();
      //get other values
   }
}
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

First get the `userid` of the current user, the userid is under the `users` node in your database, then let the datasnapshot be at `contacts` node, loop inside of it and get all the values.